# Why are my Eclipse project builds so slow?

Tags: eclipse

We use Eclipse (Indigo, with STS).   Certain of our projects take inordinately long to build.  Often the progress indicator sticks on, say, 87%, for 30 seconds.

I'm trying to find out what Eclipse is spending it's time on during the build cycle.  I hope to be able to optimize the build or disable components that are causing it to be so slow.  I'd like to see a log file saying ("compiling java code", "processing resources", etc).

I've poked around the log files in the .metadata directory.  I've looked on the Eclipse site for tips.  I've tried using "-debug" when starting Eclipse.  I still can't find the information I'm looking for.

Is there any way to get Eclipse to spit out a log of what activities it is spending its time on when it builds a project?

Comment: Check Task Manager if Eclipse swaps.  It may also be an antivirus doing its job on your Java files.

Comment: how many projects u have in your workspace?

Comment: Different devs here have different number of projects open (from 1-10). One of our projects is particularly egregious, even by itself - it's very big. Many of us have 64-bit, 8GB, SSD drive machines, and it's still slow. I want to optimize the build times, but I have no data by which to do so. That's the big problem.

Comment: or if you accidentially refer to items on a network drive.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of projects are these? Java? Dynamic Web? Two things to look at for hints about what's going on are in the project Properties dialog; look at the **Builders** section and the **Validation** section. Try disabling the validations to see if that makes a difference in your build times.

To get some insight into what's happening at the times when the build seems to hang, try setting the `-debug` and `-consoleLog` options, as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock#Using_eclipse_-consolelog).

Comment: Yes, we've played with disabling builders and validation. The problem persists. Sometimes during a full build Eclipse will hang at, say, 47% for 60-90 seconds.  I want to know why. What is it doing? Is there no possibility in Eclipse of ever knowing what it's doing? There's no logging facility whatsoever to be invoked?

Comment: I edited my answer to include pointers on enabling debug and logging.

Comment: That gives me some output but it's not detailed enough, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, that's all there is. If you have the stack dump for a time when it looks hung, I suggest posting that to the forums (http://www.eclipse.org/forums/) to see if anyone can provide any more help. Which forum to post to kind of depends on what types of projects you have (which I asked in my initial answer).

Comment: what are the repercussions of disabling validation?

Answer (score 3):

Disable your virus scanner software for your workspace and project directories. I increased the speed of my build in that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to edit   **Windows->preference->general->workspace->build order** to edit the default that exist according to your project need.

And check the **maximum number of iteration when building with cycle**.

I hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since eclipse is a Java application, the usual debugging tools are at your disposal. In particular, you might try connecting to eclipse with JConsole and inspect the thread dump taken when the build "hangs", or run eclipse within a profiler.

You might find out things like a validator trying to download an xml schema, and waiting for the timeout since eclipse is not configured to use the corpoate proxy server - something which is very hard to find out by other means ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Look into Apache Ant build scripts. Eclipse has support to auto generate them as a starting point instead of coding the whole thing by hand. The shop I worked in used tuned ANT scripts to optimize and control build order. We then piped output to log files using shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and replace with this [aapt](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1907281) . My build for a particular project went from 3 minutes to 41 seconds....

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but thought of sharing my solution. I was using eclipse Luna and I noted that when you keep on working on a GIT branch without checking into git over the time the build becomes very slow. In my case I just deleted the folder .git and the file .gitignore and the build was very fast. Please note that this will disconnect eclipse from git, therefore use this aproach only if you know how to connect back to git branch using git commands.